How do i go about making a 3d smile that conforms to a sphere
I am currently attempting to make an original 3d character and i am having trouble making a smile that pokes out of the sphere.
My current attempt was as follows:
-I added a 2d plane and traced the 2d smile (half of it, using mirror modifier)
-I added a solidify modifier to give it thickness
-I added a proxy plane which i subdivided via loop cuts
-Joined the proxy plane with the smile plane using ctrl p and selecting object (i selected the smile plane first)
-Added a surface deform modifier to smile plane and bound it to the proxy plane
-Added a shrinkwrap modifier to the proxy plane and gave it the head as an origin
-The result was not what i wanted so i played around with scale, subdivison, thickness etc to get to the point i am currently at.
I also tried creating the smile first and then just giving it the shrinkwrap modifier but that did not yield the results i hoped for.
It is almost at the point i want it to be, however the sides at the top poke out which is not intended, the smile is not "droopy" enough and the entire smile goes to high. You can also see that in the middle of the smile there is a bump which also appears at the bottom side of the smile.
If i try to delete certain faces or vertices the entire smile gets messed up. I also believe that the topolgy is quite messed up and will be an issue when trying to add the "teeth" and rigging.
I feel like i am complicating and that there is a really simple solution.
How would you guys go about creating the desired effect?
(images below for my reference, the current state and the topology of the smile)


I want it to look like it looks now, so a 3d object poking out of the head and then either the lines in the smile in the reference photo would be indented or the space between the lines further extruded (probably the first option but i would like to see both)

First thing would probably be deciding how exactly you want it to look. It could be lines, it could be some solid geometry representing lines, it could be actual 3d form of teeth, it  could be just a material, could be empty space where the lines are... What do you want it to look like?

@MartynasŽiemys I want it to look like it looks now, so a 3d object poking out of the head and then either the lines in the smile in the reference photo would be indented or the space between the lines further extruded (probably the first option but i would like to see both)

This method is fairly straightforward: https://youtu.be/uqaxd9gMQMU?feature=shared

I would use some duplicated rotated geometry from the sphere itself and then shrinkwrap modifier to constrain it to the sphere while moving vertices and possibly applying the shrinkwrap a couple of times to correct the positions of verts. Relax function from Loop Tools add-on would be useful to get edges more smooth. I would make some geometry with flow of topology matching the teeth on the 3d sphere that resembles a mouth and looks like the reference from the front. Then it would be easier to make separate teeth from it. That would require the topology of the sphere to not be messy.

Proportional editing would be helpful while moving vertices.
